# How to select data between time arrival and departure column?

Tags: mysql

I want to select data from mysql where data arr_time >= date(H:i:s) and dep_time <= date(H:i:s), how can I do this ?

because I have trying to use this, and there's no result.
my query is :

```
SELECT * FROM krl_schedule WHERE arr_time >= '$nowhour' AND dep_time <= '$nowhour' AND sts='Bekasi' AND sts_to!='Bekasi'
```

My table is krl_schedule

```
=======================================================================================
id  |   train_no  |  sts_from  |    sts    |  sts_to   |   arr_time   |    dep_time   |
=======================================================================================
1   |   100A      |  Cikarang  |  Cibitung |  Gambir   |   06:20:00   |   06:31:00    |
2   |   100B      |  Cikarang  |  Bekasi   |  Manggarai|   07:10:00   |   07:29:00    |
3   |   200A      |  Cikarang  |  Tambun   |  Bekasi   |   07:20:00   |   07:32:00    |
4   |   200B      |  Cikarang  |  Bekasi   |  Kota     |   08:20:00   |   08:31:00    |
```

And I want the result is the data with id 2 if `$nowhour` is between the `arr_time` and `dep_time`

```
2   |   100B      |  Cikarang  |  Bekasi   |  Manggarai|   07:10:00   |   07:29:00    |
```

my purpose is, to find out this train stops at **Bekasi** station in 07:20:00.

Comment: You actually want arr_time to be < $nowhour.

Comment: I've edited my query in question to be simplified

Comment: Well then it's over-simplified to the point of banality, isn't it? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Note that we have no idea what value is contained within your variable

Comment: Wow, why does this question have so many downvotes? It seems like a well structured question, am I missing something?

Comment: Also, try arr_time <= and dep_time >=, I think your mistake was that you put the signs the wrong way around

Comment: Idk for that, may I've mistakes at the first @RulerOfTheWorld

Comment: What is the exact value of `$nowhour`?

Comment: $nowhour is 07:20:00 @SebastianBrosch
before train number 100B  go away from Bekasi station at 07:29:00, where that train already on platform at 07:10:00

Comment: You are trying to search for: arr_time <= time <= dep_time. Therefore, arr_time <= currtime, dep_time >= currtime. Try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following using [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html):

```
SELECT * 
FROM krl_schedule 
WHERE '$nowhour' BETWEEN arr_time AND dep_time 
  AND sts = 'Bekasi' 
  AND sts_to <> 'Bekasi'
```

... or

```
SELECT * 
FROM krl_schedule 
WHERE arr_time <= '$nowhour' AND dep_time >= '$nowhour'
  AND sts = 'Bekasi' 
  AND sts_to <> 'Bekasi'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f738d28f88e6c4e9dffa0d57c831467)

Comment: Oh my God, it's work like a magic with first query.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code using BETWEEN function where 07:20:00 is your $nowhour

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
 krl_schedule 
WHERE '07:20:00' BETWEEN arr_time AND dep_time 
AND sts = 'Bekasi' 
AND sts_to != 'Bekasi'
```

so your final query will be like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
 krl_schedule 
WHERE '$nowhour' BETWEEN arr_time AND dep_time 
AND sts = 'Bekasi' 
AND sts_to != 'Bekasi'
```